# Reading the same .RData file from multiple processes

Tags: r, io, rdata

I am trying to load a bunch of RData files simultaneously from different processes.  For instance:

```
# script1.R
for (i in 1:1000) x <- get(load(sprintf('file%d.RData', i)))

# script2.R
for (i in 1:1000) x <- get(load(sprintf('file%d.RData', i)))

# from terminal:
> Rscript script1.R &
> Rscript script2.R
```

However, when the two processes are reading the file at the same time I get two different kinds of errors:

```
# error msg 1
Error: bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
In addition: Warnings message:
file 'file345.RData' has magic number ''
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated
...

# error msg 2
Error: error reading from connection
...
```

I am running the above code on CentOS6 with Microsoft R Open 3.3.0. This is the first time I have seen this.  Does anyone know what went wrong?

Comment: Surprising. No problem running this example on Ubuntu 14.04 with R unstable/3.4.

Comment: This is probably very naive, but what happens if you try to load only one file without sourcing scripts? (Could it be that some of those files were made using something else then `save`, e.g. `saveRDS?`)

Comment: I didn't fix the issue, however, it now runs quite smooth the next day after a system reboot.  I am wondering if it has something to do with my system setting.